# How do I asynchronously update Completion results in an ICompletionSource?

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-sdk

I'm trying to implement code-completion in Visual Studio for the Google Dart language. I've successfully implemented some hard-coded values in an ICompletionSource [like this](https://github.com/DanTup/DartVS/blob/d33e5499c234dcb240d884d8c821c73f787cff1b/DanTup.DartVS.Vsix/Completion/CompletionSourceProvider.cs):

```
class CompletionSource : ICompletionSource
{
    CompletionSourceProvider provider;
    ITextBuffer buffer;
    ITextDocumentFactoryService textDocumentFactory;
    DartAnalysisService analysisService;

    public CompletionSource(CompletionSourceProvider provider, ITextBuffer buffer, ITextDocumentFactoryService textDocumentFactory, DartAnalysisService analysisService)
    {
        this.provider = provider;
        this.buffer = buffer;
        this.textDocumentFactory = textDocumentFactory;
        this.analysisService = analysisService;
    }

    public void AugmentCompletionSession(ICompletionSession session, IList<CompletionSet> completionSets)
    {
        var triggerPoint = session.GetTriggerPoint(buffer.CurrentSnapshot);
        if (triggerPoint == null)
            return;

        var applicableTo = buffer.CurrentSnapshot.CreateTrackingSpan(new SnapshotSpan(triggerPoint.Value, 1), SpanTrackingMode.EdgeInclusive);

        var completions = new ObservableCollection<Completion>();
        completions.Add(new Completion("Something1"));
        completions.Add(new Completion("Something2"));
        completions.Add(new Completion("Something3"));

        completionSets.Add(new CompletionSet("All", "All", applicableTo, completions, Enumerable.Empty<Completion>()));
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        GC.SuppressFinalize(true);
    }
}
```

This all works fine. However, in the real implementation, the act of getting completions is slow (it's handled by another process), so I need to be able to return these results later.

If I do all the work synchronously, the editor hangs (no surprise) for the duration of the request.

The documentation is pretty poor. I've tried all sorts; including using both `IEnumerable<Completion>` arguments in the `CompletionSet` constructor; inserting values into the `ObservableCollection<Completion>`, calling `Recalculate()` on both the session and the CompletionSet.

Here's an implementation that inserts a second value into the completion list after 1 second. This doesn't work; but is a starting point for anyone wanting to try:

```
    public void AugmentCompletionSession(ICompletionSession session, IList<CompletionSet> completionSets)
    {
        var triggerPoint = session.GetTriggerPoint(buffer.CurrentSnapshot);
        if (triggerPoint == null)
            return;

        ITextDocument doc;
        if (!textDocumentFactory.TryGetTextDocument(buffer, out doc))
            return;

        var applicableTo = buffer.CurrentSnapshot.CreateTrackingSpan(new SnapshotSpan(triggerPoint.Value, 1), SpanTrackingMode.EdgeInclusive);

        var completions = new ObservableCollection<Completion>();
        completions.Add(new Completion("Hard-coded..."));

        var completionSet = new CompletionSet("All", "All", applicableTo, Enumerable.Empty<Completion>(), completions);
        completionSets.Add(completionSet);

        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000); // Wait 1s
            completions.Add(new Completion("Danny")); // This doesn't update the code-completion list; why not?
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than asynchronously update your completion source, you could asynchronously trigger the completion itself in your implementation of `IIntellisenseController`. When you detect the need for a completion, first perform a background calculation of the desired results, and then use the `ICompletionBroker` to trigger the display of the results.

Comment: Interesting! I don't have an `IIntellisenseController`, currently an [OleCommandTarget-based controller]https://github.com/DanTup/DartVS/blob/a9b2c4046322e9eef4709db71e7e3833c9277b0d/DanTup.DartVS.Vsix/Completion/CompletionController.cs); I presume this is an old API I didn't know there was an updated version of? I'll give this a go :)

Comment: Ignore that; seems I did it correctly... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372314.aspx shows an IOldCommandTarget :(

Comment: But I can probably still tweak it to work more like you suggested; will give it a go soon!

Comment: @DannyTuppeny The key on that page is making `TriggerCompletion` asynchronous, and updating the command handler to account for the fact that it could still be running the next time a character is pressed (i.e. don't call `Filter` prior to it appearing, or schedule `Filter` to run after the trigger task completes).

Comment: Finally getting back to this... I don't have a TriggerCompletion, only a `session.Start()`? My implementation files are [here](https://github.com/DanTup/DartVS/tree/master/DanTup.DartVS.Vsix/Completion), not sure if I'm doing things differently to you expect (I don't have an `IIntellisenseController`, I have an `IOleCommandTarget` for `CompletionController` and `ICompletionSourceProvider`/`ICompletionSource`s :/